# How do you call an async method in html?

Tags: javascript, angular, async-await, angular13

Having

```
export class AppComponent {

  private getMyVar(n: number){
    return Promise.resolve(n * n);    
  }

  public async getVar(n: number): Promise<number> {
    let result = await this.getMyVar(n);
    return result;
  }
}
```

how do you call the `getVar` from the HTML template?

I tried

```
<p>getVar = {{ this.getVar(9) | async }}</p>
```

but this does not seem to work. The CodePen [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-1wd2of?file=src/app/app.component.html)

Comment: You should look for async pipes with rxjs Observables/subjects.

Comment: 1. If your function is returning a promise, you don't need to make it an `async` function - it should just be a regular function that returns a promise. 2. I am not an angular expert but having experience of working with react and vue, I think you need to call `getVar` from somewhere else in your component and have the `getVar` function update some state. Inside your template, you should use the state that `getVar` function updates.

Comment: `this` is implicit, just call `getVar(9) | async`

Comment: Referencing `this` in the template used to be an error, at least in previous versions of Angular. Just check the Angular guide: https://angular.io/guide/interpolation

Comment: @serge Could you please give us more details about your use case? Calling the function directly from the component's template is not generally a good practice.